# Images uploading to wrong folder

Tags: images, uploads

Images keep uploading to /uploads/2010/07 instead of /uploads/2011/06. Permissions are set to 777 just to find out if 755 is an issue, and it's not.

I don't have anything in Media to define a new path.

It just keeps uploading to the oldest folder. This was an XML dump from another WP to the new WP, so I'm not sure if that had anything to do with it, or not.

I can see the image files fine and they post in the post editor, they're just going to the oldest folder and it's not autocreating a new one.

I'm running the latest wp 3.1.3. I do have a bunch of plug-ins, the image thumbnail regenerator is one, and I've got a bunch of plugins for sidebar widgets, but nothing out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tony,

are you creating a new post or editing an older post from 2010/07?

I've found that the folder relates to when the post/page was created initially.

Comment: That's probably it. I didn't realize that, even after working with WP for 8 years!